# Error with Spring Boot Jsp sample application

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a Spring Boot application with JSP template. I'm having some problems with it so I'm comparing my application with Spring Boot's sample jsp application: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

To my surprise I've got the same problem with the sample. I'm going to try to describe the steps I've followed:

- Download spring-boot: git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot
- Move to a stable version: git checkout v1.4.0.RELEASE
- Move to the sample application: cd spring-boot/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/
- Run the application: mvn spring-boot:run

In the application's logs I see the available request mappings: /, /foo and /error

I do this request curl -XGET localhost:8080/ and I get this answer:

```
{"timestamp":1471504557212,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

The result that I expected was the html of welcome.jsp. It seems that there is a problem when Spring Mvc tries to render welcome.jsp.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the Name of yout Project? You should add this to your URL

Comment: i did the exact same thing you wrote, got the desired html page

Comment: Thanks Kaushal! It seems to be a silly thing... I'll keep looking for the solution.